# Why are my fitted coefficients so well-determined?

Tags: regression, standard-error, fitting

I have a dataset of $N$ points each with some different value $y$ I try to fit the data to the form $a\cos(2\pi t)+b\sin(2\pi t)+c\cos(4\pi t)+d\sin(4\pi t)+e$. When I'm looking at the standard errors in the fitted parameters for $a,b,c,d,e$, they are really, really small. For $a=-11$, the standard error in $a$ is only around $0.03$. This well-determinedness is kind of unsettling and I doubt its correctness.

Should note that my $N$ is fairly large, around 400, and I'm using Mathematica to find standard errors in the fitted parameters (i.e. [ParameterTable]).

How can one compute the errors in the fitted parameters? Are the standard errors for the parameters it? They seem too small to be true.

Comment: Your question is absolutely opaque. One might speak of fitting a function $y = a\cos(2\pi t)+b\sin(2\pi t)+c\cos(4\pi t)+d\sin(4\pi t)+e$ where your sample includes some observed values of $y$ and of $t,$, but you speak of $a_i,$ $i=1,\ldots,N$ without saying whether those are in the role of $y$ or of $t.$ Your question as now written cannot be understood.

Comment: Removed the a's. I just want to say each point has some value. The main point of my question i suppose is how to find the errors in the fitted parameters for a NonlinearModelfit of the said function performed on a dataset?

Comment: Your question remains incomprehensible. You say "each with some different value $y$", but then nothing called $\text{“}y\text{''}$ appears in what follows.

Comment: Suppose one has $$ y = a\cos(2\pi t) + b \sin(2\pi t)+c\cos(4\pi t)+d\sin(4\pi t)+e. $$ Then data could consist of observed values of $y$ and of $t,$ and one might be able to estimate the coefficients. But if you say you have observed values of $y,$ but not of $t,$ and you write $$ a\cos(2\pi t)+b\sin(2\pi t) + c\cos(4\pi t)+d\sin(4\pi t)+e $$ with no variable called $y,$ then at best we can guess what you mean, and guessing is what I am doing here.

Comment: I'm reacting to the fact that you're being difficult. You _still_ haven't said anything about any values of $t$, although I've mentioned that several times.

Comment: I suggest adding the tag "mathematica" to the question.

Comment: Could you tell us why you think that the confidence intervals of the fit parameters are too small?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHardy. What is Y? What is t? Why are you fitting a curve like the one you have? My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you write this in a way that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Mathematica calculates the standard errors of a the fit. However, I reckon that the point estimator and its standard deviation is calculated via
\begin{align}
    \hat{{\beta}} &= ({X}^T{X})^{-1} {X}^T {y} \\
%%%
      \hat{Sd}[\hat{\beta}_j] &=\sqrt{
      \hat{\textrm{Cov}}[\hat{{\beta}}]_{jj}} 
= \hat{\sigma} \cdot \sqrt{\big[({X}^T {X})^{-1}\big]_{jj}}
\end{align}
where ${X}$ is the design matrix! [Note, that $y$ and $\beta$ are vectors in the upper formulae and the hat indicates an estimate.]

An alternative way to check Mathematic's estimates is to produce fake data, from which you know the correct coefficients. By fitting this fake data you get a feeling whether or not Mathematica is reliable.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was asking for. Sorry to all above where the question was unclear. May I ask how exactly does one simulate synthetic data given correct coefficients?

Comment: Well, you just use your formula and generate normally distributed random numbers for your $e$.